# Idiom to get just the "own object" and not the prototype chain

Tags: javascript

Is there a recognised idiom to get just the own-object in JavaScript? i.e. I would like to chop off the prototype chain for an object, in IE10 and above.

```
function O() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
}
O.prototype = { bar: 'bar' }

var o = new O();

for(var v in o) { 
  console.log(v); // foo bar
}

// ...but I just want an object representing the own properties and their values

o.__proto__ = null; // But I need this to work in IE10
for(var v in o) { 
  console.log(v); // foo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) or [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fr81nozc/1/)

```
function O() {
  this.foo = 'foo';
}
O.prototype = { bar: 'bar' }

var o = new O();

for(var v in o) { 
    console.log(v); // foo bar
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  console.log("getOwnPropertyNames() " + val);
});

Object.keys(o).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  console.log("keys() " + val);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` to exclude prototype properties:

```
for(var v in o) { 
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
   console.log(v); // foo
  }
}
```

Or use `Object.keys` to retrieve only the instance properties:

```
var props = Object.keys(o);
console.log(props); //=> ['foo']
```

To be able to use or not use a prototype for a som constructor, you can create a  factory function for that constructor, something like (tested and working in IE10):

```js
function OFactory( useproto ) {
  
  function O() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
  }
  
  O.prototype = useproto;
  return new O;
  
}

var o = OFactory({bar: 'bar'});
var p = OFactory();
var q = OFactory({bar: 'bar', foox: 'foox', fooy: 'fooy'});


for (var l in o) {
  log('o['+l+']');
}

for (var l in p) {
  log('p['+l+']');
}

for (var l in q) {
  log('q['+l+']');
}
  
function log(str) {
  var res = document.querySelector('#result'),
      current = res.textContent;
  res.textContent = [current, str].join('\n');
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: you have an "!" too much. Now it only logs the prototype properties.

Comment: OK, so direct manipulation of the chain is not possible in IE10?

Comment: @BenAston: I suppose there are ways to manipulate the chain, but I'd say it would smell nasty (as in 'code smell')

Comment: @KooiInc Understood, and what is that way for IE10? i.e. what is the equivalent of `o.__proto__ = null;`?

Comment: @BenAston: I don't think there is an equivalent. But it may be an idea to  reason the other way around: see the suggestion in the revised answer

Answer (score 2):

You want to have a look on [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), respectively [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). The difference between the two is, `getOwnPropertyNames` will also enumerate non-enumerable-flagged properties, while `keys()` will hide those out.

*The Object.getOwnPropertyNames() method returns an array of all properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct way to just get the object without prototype-chain, but you could change your loops so it hops over those elements:

```
for(var v in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
      //Voodoo magic here.
  }
}
```